# Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /includes/common.inc

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I built a simple function to modify the default main menu style on Drupal.

But I am receiving the following error now, what am I doing wrong?

edit: I just identified the string that causes the error; `$link['href']`. But I need to get the links, I dont know how to make it work...

```
function corporate_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html='<li>
            <a href="#" class="button holdmecloser_btn white_f btn-hasdd">
                <span class="ico-arrow-white">'.t('sections').'</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sub">
                <ul class="holdmecloser_bg white_f">';
                foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
                   $html .= '<li>'.l($link['title'], $link['href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => 'white_f'))).'</li> <!--<li><a href="" class="white_f">home</a></li>-->';
                 }  
                $html .= '</ul>
            </div>
        </li>';

  return $html;
}
```

Comment: I'd say that the variable `$variables` isn't what you expect. Either it's a string, or it contains an array of strings, not an array of arrays. `var_dump` it and post the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, class attributes must be an array in Drupal 7.
Changing the following line fixed my problem

wrong

```
           $html .= '<li>'.l($link['title'], $link['href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => 'white_f'))).'</li> <!--<li><a href="" class="white_f">home</a></li>-->';
```

correct

```
$html .= '<li>'.l($link['title'], $link['href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => array('white_f')))).'</li>';
```

Comment: Correct:  _If element 'class' is included, it must be an array;_ 

source [function l](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add attributes to your main menu items, why not use menu attributes module?